# MongoDB near query is failing retrieving locations

Tags: java, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoid

I am using MongoDB, with a NEAR query for retrieving locations.

When I use in my query longitude=-90 its working fine, but if I have a longitude lower then -90.. the MongoDB is breaking.

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error -1: 'Can't parse filter / create query' on server ******.*****.com:4353. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Can't parse filter / create query", "operationTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1561702150, "i" : 1 } }, "$clusterTime" : { "clusterTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1561702150, "i" : 1 } }, "signature" : { "hash" : { "$binary" : "XWJh9UrqNGU9NDwMOx2MsG4yJcA=", "$type" : "00" }, "keyId" : { "$numberLong" : "6698286035400392705" } } } }
    at com.mongodb.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:164) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.4.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:295) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.4.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:255) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.4.jar!/:na]
```

Why the "near" query is accepting only value up to -90. And breaking when the longitude is lower than -90?

Comment: Are you sure that you are passing the coordinates in the right order? Just in case it is `[longitude, latitude, altitude] `

Comment: AFAIK in MongoDB, `altitude` is currently ignored. Only the first two (longitude, latitude) are procesed.

Comment: @kevinadi it is not required, but that's still a valid Geojson.